# How to make a custom draggable script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an object draggable using Javascript. fortunately I managed to build what i wanted. each time I run the code, i can take and drag the object for about 8/11 times then my browser start freezing. I tried using chrome, Firefox and safari they all freezed after about 10 times of picking the object and leaving it. I went to jquery website i made sure that all the functions are used in the right way. I could not find any reason for what is happening. can anyone help please?

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
        <style>
            .draggable {
                width:400px;
                height:30px;
                background-color:black;
                position:absolute;
                top:10px;
                left:1px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function moveobject() {
                $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
                    $("#draggable1").css("top", event.pageY - plustop);
                    $("#draggable1").css("left", event.pageX - plusleft);
                });
                $("#draggable1").click(function() {
                    $(document).unbind();
                    $("#draggable1").click(moveobject);
                });
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#draggable1").click(function() {
                    $("#draggable1").mousemove(function(e) {
                        var top = $("#draggable1").css("top");
                        var left = $("#draggable1").css("left");
                        top = top.replace("px", "");
                        left = left.replace("px", "");
                        plusleft = (e.pageX - left)
                        plustop = (e.pageY - top)
                        $(this).unbind("mousemove");
                    });
                    moveobject();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='draggable' id='draggable1'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

It's easy to use..

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <style>
        #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me around</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Custom draggable Live demo](http://jsbin.com/ASOGoluw/1/edit)

```
$(function(){

    var $el = $('#draggable1'),
        $par = $(window),        // $el move -> available area
        atX,atY,wW,wH,
        elW = $el.outerWidth(true),
        elH = $el.outerHeight(true);

    $el.on('mousedown', function(e) {
      var off = $el.offset();
      wW = $par.width();
      wH = $par.height();
      atX = e.pageX - off.left;
      atY = e.pageY - off.top;
      $(document).on('mousemove',moveHandler).on('mouseup',stopHandler);      
    });     

    function moveHandler(e) {
      var X = e.pageX-atX;
      var Y = e.pageY-atY;
      X = Math.min( Math.max(0, X), wW-elW); // remove this lines if you don't
      Y = Math.min( Math.max(0, Y), wH-elH); // need to restrict movement
      $el.css({left: X, top: Y});
    }       
    function stopHandler() {
       $(document).off('mousemove',moveHandler).off('mouseup',stopHandler);
    }

});
```

Not much versatile for more elements, so you can play around and expand a bit this
[basic **PLUGIN**](http://jsbin.com/ASOGoluw/3/edit)  I created to use like:

```
$(function(){
  $('#draggable1').dragg({containment:window});
  $('#draggable2').dragg(); // not contained
  $('#test').dragg({containment:"#par"});
});
```

PLUGIN:

```
(function($) {   
    $.fn.extend({        
        dragg: function(opt) {
          var S = { 
            containment: false
          };
          opt = $.extend(S, opt);

return this.each(function(){
    var $el=$(this),atX,atY,atXP=0,atYP=0, wW=0,wH=0,
        elW=$el.outerWidth(true),
        elH=$el.outerHeight(true),
        $cont = S.containment;

    $el.on('mousedown', function(e) {
      var off = $el.offset();
      if($cont && $cont!==window){
        var parOff = $($cont).offset();
        atXP = parOff.left;
        atYP = parOff.top;
      }
      wW = $($cont).width();
      wH = $($cont).height();
      atX = e.pageX - off.left;
      atY = e.pageY - off.top;
      $(document).on('mousemove',move).on('mouseup',stop);                
    });

    function move(e) {
      var X=e.pageX-atXP-atX, Y=e.pageY-atYP-atY;
      if($cont){
          X = Math.min( Math.max(0, X), wW-elW);
          Y = Math.min( Math.max(0, Y), wH-elH);
      }
      $el.css({left: X, top: Y});
    }
    function stop() {
       $(document).off('mousemove',move).off('mouseup',stop);
    }

});

        }
    });  
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1 for actually showing how to do this instead of just pointing to a library.

Answer (score 1):

To make an object draggable, I highly recommend using a library like [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

It adds the [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable) functionality you are looking for and you don't have to deal with these finicky bits all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto the above about using jQuery or some other library that's already worked this out.  But to you specific code, it looks like you are binding and unbinding event handlers over and over again? why?  This will likely lead to undesirable behavior.  If you really need conditional behavior it's better to use a variable to guard the state of one event handlers and just have it return without doing anything if the state is active.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why binding and unbinding will cause and undesirable behavior ?

Comment: While it can be done, I'm not sure it should be done.  I don't know if the speed of registering and unregistering event handlers is something that's really promised to be particularly fast.  Maybe it's no big deal, I don't know.  But just using a flag on the function would be a lot faster to do (instead of manipulating the large data structures that handle the event listeners) and would be easier to debug.

Basically my concern is that you're dynamically changing the code, instead of the state that it's operating on.